# Fetch Azure storage dacpac file in ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-devops-server-2019

Is there a way to get data from Azure Storage like dacpac, zip etc and put in drop folder in CI/CD pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hm, for saving files **to** Azure Storage, there is a [Azure File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203). So you probably have to either use **PowerShell** (like the [Set-AzStorageBlobContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell#upload-blobs-to-the-container?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) cmdlet) or using the [azcopy CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) (you might have to find an image that contains the binary)